# paperclip save failed but no error logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I'm blocked on a strange problem:
I'm using paperclip 2.3.16 with rails 3.0.9

I have a model Upload containing the attribute photo as attachement `has_attached_file :photo,`.
In the client side everything seems OK. the Upload create action is called and the @upload.save method is called but returning false. 
When I look into the /tmp file I see that the photo was correctly uploaded and processed (there is resize and watermarking processing) but nothing in the public/system dir nor in the data base.
The server log gives:

```
Started POST "/uploads" for 192.168.1.10 at 2011-08-14 19:51:29 +0200
  Processing by UploadsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"Filename"=>"photos_irlande_gr.jpg", "folder"=>"/properties/", "property_uploadtoken"=>"fHTVm09QCxMwn2dKOjIcWca+tFTxgW10", "_site_session"=>"BAh7B0kiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRiIlODk2MTZhNzg3NzQ3YjBhZmIwOTUyMzIzOGNkYzY5MzFJIhBfY3NyZl90b2tlbgY7AEZJIjFTS29ZUHpNalhBQXFPZEYzU0xOT3c1QlNUR2FmK0xwUDNrTzNvMzlpZmhjPQY7AEY=--47d7b48ddc0f75e56b05f61cdbe519bbf692020a", "authenticity_token"=>"SKoYPzMjXAAqOdF3SLNOw5BSTGaf+LpP3kO3o39ifhc=", "fileext"=>"*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png", "Filedata"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xa472048 @original_filename="photos_irlande_gr.jpg", @content_type="application/octet-stream", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Filedata\"; filename=\"photos_irlande_gr.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20110814-1818-1lba9ph>>, "Upload"=>"Submit Query"}
  Upload Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `uploads`.* FROM `uploads` WHERE (updated_at < '2011-08-14 16:51:29' AND property_id IS NULL)
#<Upload:0xa107700>
  SQL (0.3ms)  LOCK TABLES uploads WRITE
  SQL (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `uploads` WHERE `uploads`.`uploadtoken` = 'fHTVm09QCxMwn2dKOjIcWca+tFTxgW10'
=========save begin========
  SQL (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
=========save end========
  SQL (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `uploads` WHERE `uploads`.`uploadtoken` = 'fHTVm09QCxMwn2dKOjIcWca+tFTxgW10'
  SQL (0.1ms)  UNLOCK TABLES
```

here is the begining of the Upload create action

```
  def create
    #remove orphelin photos
    clean_uploads

    newparams = coerce(params)
    @upload = Upload.new(newparams[:upload])

    logger.debug @upload

    @success= true

    #critical section begin
    lock    
    check_limitation
    logger.debug "=========save begin========" 
    @upload.save    
    logger.debug "=========save end========"
```

I have encountered paperclip problems before but at lease I had errors on the server logs. this time nothing. How to investigate?

Comment: what does `which identify` returns?

Comment: imagemagick is correclty installed

Comment: Does the Upload return true for #valid? If so, perhaps some file permissions issue is involved.

Comment: I noticed that I'm able to write the @upload.errors to the logs.
The problem is coming from my validation on MIME type.

    {:photo_content_type=>["is not one of image/jpeg, image/gif, image/png"]}


thanks